# Commenting in Dynamic CSS

Tags: php, css, dynamic, comments

I'm working with a dynamic stylesheet, ie: style.php, beginning with the code

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/css'); ?>
```

How should I comment in such a file?

From my own experience, html style commenting tends to cause some trouble (deactivating upcoming styles) whereas css style commenting tends to be ignored.

On the other hand, Notepad++ colors the html comments green, while leaving the css comments black.

Anyway, if there's an official answer, or some special rules, I'd like to know.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not PHP comments?

Comment: same as css comments, right? (plus the single-line option //)
(Note I added above: Notepad++ doesn't color them as comments.)

Comment: This sounds like more of a problem for the editor you are using, and incorrect syntax highlighting, than a question about what you should use. /*There is only one way to comment in css*/

Comment: This chould be of interest http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/1673ef4d or this http://superuser.com/questions/235320/different-language-syntax-highlighting-within-same-file. Personally I found other editors like `e`, `sublime` or `editplus` to be better than `notepad++` for quite a few reasons... highlighting being one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the comments to appear in the generated CSS, then use CSS comments, like this:

```
echo "/* My css comment */";
echo "body { margin: 0 }";
```

If you don't want them to be visible in the generated CSS and only want to be able to read them when editing the PHP file, then use regular PHP comments:

```
// Just a regular PHP comment, this won't be visible in the generated CSS!
echo "body { margin: 0 }";
/* You can use this style of comments too, it's up to you what you prefer. */
```

Comment: PHP comments should be colorized properly, but Notepad++ (or any other editor) won't be able to tell that that you are echoing CSS comments, it will treat them as it would any other string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/css');

    echo "* { margin: 0; }";
    // Comments 1
    # Comments 2
    /* Comments 3 */
?>
```

Comment: ah - Clarkson, are you are saying that I should make sure to wrap my comments in php tags? (And that I can also comment with hashmarks?)

Comment: It is just for owner of `.php` file. If you want to see comments in css file, you could follow @Matt Cain 's solution.